# How do I get the color of a pixel using AVFoundation with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, avfoundation

I'm aware that AVFoundation can be used to take videos, and photos. I'm currently using it for taking photos, and I'm quite new to AVFoundation. I have my iOS programmed to the point that I can start a session and capture a photo and save it if I would like. I'd like to know how I grab all of the pixels from an image that I take, and then check the RGB values of certain pixels. For example, if I wanted to grab the pixel in the center of the image and then acquire it's RGB value to compare against something else. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!